# How to prevent a pod from triggering the Cluster autoscaler

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to tell Kubernetes that a pod should **not** trigger the cluster autoscaler?   In other words the pod should only run if there is spare capacity on the cluster.  If there isn't room on the cluster for the pod, it should just stay in the pending state and the cluster autoscaler should ignore it rather than spinnning up a node for the pod.

Edit: this is on GKE using its standard autoscaler.

Comment: How did you configure your autoscaler? It is a bare metal cluster or cloud managed (gke/eks)? Please post your configuration if possible.